# CloudBees Jenkins Android JUnit Test Emulator won't start

Tags: android, junit, android-emulator, jenkins, cloudbees

I am unable to run any JUnit test cases for a simple Hello World Android app. I keep trying different settings but nothing works.

One error is as follows:

[android] /opt/android/android-sdk-linux/tools/android create avd -f -a -c 128M -s WVGA800 -n hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-10 -t android-10

```
There is more than one system image defined for platform 'android-10'.
Pick an image to use and set it in the 'Target ABI' config field.
Valid ABIs: armeabi, x86
```

If I choose anything but x86, I get different error. If I choose x86, the message says "Emulator did not appear to start; giving up"

If anyone has a working Hello World example, that would be helpful. I have no idea what I can even try to make progress.

Thanks

Comment: What about the error "Pick an image to use and set it in the 'Target ABI' config field."? Did you enter, for example, `x86` in the Target ABI config field?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in original posting.

Comment: Have you tried targeting anything beyond android-10?

Answer (score 0):

see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14901
we are investigating this issue, but don't have a fix yet

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a side effect introduced by the fix for [JENKINS-14741](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14901).

It should be fixed soon.